# Issue with Google Apps Script, Microsoft Graph API, and OneDrive Integration

Tags: azure, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Google Apps Script to interact with the Microsoft Graph API for accessing OneDrive files. However,   I'm encountering an issue and would appreciate some guidance.
I have a Google Apps Script that uses OAuth2 and a refresh token to obtain an access token. The script then attempts to fetch data from a OneDrive file using the Microsoft Graph API. While the initial authentication process seems to be successful (as indicated by the 'Success' log), subsequent requests to the API result in a 401 error with the message:

`{"error":{"code":"FileOpenUserUnauthorized","message":"You do not have permissions to open this file in the browser.","innerError":{"code":"unauthorizedAccessUser"}}}` 
Below is the code

```
    function main() {
      const clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
      const refreshToken = "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN";

      let data = {
        'client_id': clientId,
        'refresh_token': refreshToken,
        'redirect_uri': 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf',
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
      };

      let params = {
        'method': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'payload': data,
      };

      let res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', params);

      const tokens = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
      // console.log(tokens['access_token']);
      Logger.log('Success');
      params = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${tokens['access_token']}`
        },
      };

      res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Book1.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets/Sheet1/range(address='A1:B6')", params);
      if (res.getResponseCode().toString().startsWith('2')) {
        const json = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
        let values = json.values;
        Logger.log(values);

      } else {
        console.error()
      }
    }
```

I tried to adjust the permission of the app in Azure, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you decode the access token and paste the screenshot?

Comment: It doesn't decode it!

Comment: You have to use access token to call the API not the refresh token

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"You do not have permissions to open this file in the browser"***  usually occurs if the user doesn't have proper permissions to perform the action.

Make sure to grant **delegated** **`Files.Read.All`** Microsoft Graph API permission to the Microsoft Entra application:

[image]

Generated access token:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:RefreshToken
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
```

[image]

Make sure to **decode the access token** and check if the scope is present:

[image]

By using the above access token, **I am able to fetch the drive details of the signed in user** successfully:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get Drive - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)